# ISCSI multiple connections using the same initiator IQN

Tags: target, scsi, iscsi

Is it possible for multiple computers to connect to the same target at the same time, using the same initiator IQN?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good idea.  From RFC 3720 (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3720.txt):

> ```
>   a) iSCSI names are globally unique.  No two initiators or targets
>      can have the same name.
> ```

You may find that duplicate IQN's may work on a given target.  But even then, you must ensure that the iSCSI session ID's can not overlap, or the target may get very confused.  The combination of IQN, iSCSI session ID and target form the I_T nexus that the target will use to keep track of things.  Again, from RFC 3720:

> ```
>   c)  I_T nexus - a relationship between a SCSI Initiator Port and a
>       SCSI Target Port, according to [SAM2].  For iSCSI, this
>       relationship is a session, defined as a relationship between
>       an iSCSI Initiator's end of the session (SCSI Initiator Port)
>       and the iSCSI Target's Portal Group.  The I_T nexus can be
>       identified by the conjunction of the SCSI port names or by the
>       iSCSI session identifier SSID.  iSCSI defines the I_T nexus
>       identifier to be the tuple (iSCSI Initiator Name + 'i' + ISID,
>       iSCSI Target Name + 't' + Portal Group Tag).
> ```

This nexus object must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Possible - yes.  Good idea - no.  For this to work correctly you would need a cluster filesystem; otherwise you'll end up with corrupted data.